# WPF MVVM Change button content with loading user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a simple window with two buttons on bottom, when one button is clicked it change the view model of my main window, the name of the content button and the command.

I would like that when user click on the button change this with a loading user control i already have but i'm stacked, i don't know it's something i can implement with xaml or i need some code on my view model.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Both: ViewModel and View have to [interact](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC648329.png). E.g. command from button (View) will trigger property changes (ViewModel), which are bound to controls (View). You may want to put content into another View+ViewModel (UserControl and its ViewModel) and use `ContentControl` + datatemplates with usual binding to display it. The best appropriate solution require more details: what content is exactly you want to display, etc.

Comment: What about using a BusyIndicator?

Comment: Ok, if i understood correctly i can create two ViewModel "Button" and "LoadingButton" and then switch between this two when the user click on it. The problem now is that i have two button with different content and command, how can i dynamically assign those?
Right now in my view i have two buttons with relative bindings on my view model.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some code on your ViewModel to swap out the Button for the Loading control. You can either do this with binding ContentControls or with a Boolean property to set one to visible and the other to hidden while the loading happens.